# Media player seekbar play from start position, every time it is dragged

Tags: android, seekbar

I am trying to play a MP3 song remotely by using seek bar listener.

But when I try to drag the progress bar then it is playing from beginning of the song. It should play from that dragged position.

My code here :-

```
try{
        mediaplayer.setDataSource("http://yyy.com/yyy/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Sleep-Sanctuary.mp3");
        mediaplayer.prepareAsync(); 
        int min = 29;
        int sec = 41;

        int minc = min * 60000;
        int secc = sec * 1000;

        time = minc + secc;

        mediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            int seconds = (int) (time / 1000) % 60;
            int minutes = (int) ((time / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
            s_time.setText("" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
            seekbar.setMax(time);
            seekbar.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
            mediaplayer.seekTo(position);
            if (position == 0) {

                mediaplayer.start();
            } else {
                //if we come from a resumed activity, video playback will be paused
                mediaplayer.pause();
            }
            }
        });
        mediaplayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {

                seekbar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);                  
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                // this is when actually seekbar has been seeked to a new position
                mediaplayer.seekTo(progress);
            }
        }
    });
```

onEverySecond = new Runnable() {

```
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (seekbar != null) {
                seekbar.setProgress(mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition());

            }

                if (mediaplayer.isPlaying()) {
                seekbar.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
            }

            int startTime = mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();

            int seconds = (int) (startTime / 1000) % 60;
            int minutes = (int) ((startTime / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
            f_time.setText("" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

        }
    };
```

Comment: You set seekbar.setMax(time), but you aren't telling us what "time" is.  What is "time"?

Comment: time is duration of the song in millesecond

Comment: How can you know what the time of the MediaPlayer is before it's been prepared?  Wouldn't you want to query mp in onPrepared to know for sure?

Comment: There are other unknows.  You immediately seek to "position" but don't show where that comes from either.  Where is onEverySecond?

Comment: I cant able to get the time duration from mp.getDuration(). So that I manually convert the song time to millesecond and set it to "time". Position is set to 0

Comment: So what is the value of 'time' in some specific case you can verify?  Why can't you get duration from mp.getDuration()?  I do that all the time in my app.  Seriously, paste the entire code sample so we can see exactly what you're doing.  This lacks context.

Comment: I have done. please see the edited code

Comment: Don't hard code duration.  Use the reported duration from the prepared MediaPlayer itself to set the max value for the progress.  If you don't get this value correct, nothing may be correct.

Comment: But when the setdata Uri is an url, I mean if the mp3 is from the internet, we can't able to get the duration. It works only if the mp3 file is in local.

Comment: You can get the duration of media *after* it has been prepared.  Don't make assumptions about the duration before this.  If the duration is still somehow not available, then maybe it's a live stream that doesn't have a known ending?

Comment: How would you ever know the duration of a live stream?  It could go on forever, until the broadcast stops.

Comment: Ya, conversion is not the good idea. And that is the stable MP3 file not a live stream. I see that if the MP3 time is small I can get the duration. If it is a large one it always return 0, mine is 29.41 min so it returns 0. Is there any way to get the duration?

Comment: Not that I know of.  In this case it might not even make sense to show a seekbar because you wouldn't be able to jump around in time.